# Is it illegal to use a horn in circumstances other than which will prevent a collision

Tags: england-and-wales, traffic

I heard from a cyclist that motorists are legally prohibited from using their horns on the street to get people's attention or indeed for any reason other than to directly avert a collision.

Comment: Or indirectly. It should be used to alert other road users to your presence, for example certain blind bends, such as where a narrow lane dog-legs under a railway bridge. It's indirect because you don't even know if another vehicle is approaching. That's the point - if you could see each other you would not need to toot. Another situation is approaching a blind bend on a narrow uphill mountian road. Vehicles coming downhill are supposed to give way to you, and if they don't know you are there you'll both have to stop.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've learned such use is explicitly illegal, with some exceptions, such as the Swiss postal bus.

Comment: @gerrit we don't have Swiss postal buses here, please post the explicit link. The answer below quotes the Highway Code: *to warn other road users of your presence*. This is actually the primary reason for having the horn at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I don't have a link.  When I was in driving school, I learned it was allowed to use to avert immediate danger only.

Comment: @gerrit was that in England / Wales?

Comment: @WeatherVane - what about blasting it for fun when going through tunnels?  I thought _that_ was the primary purpose of the horn?

Comment: .. state law requires your motor vehicle be preceded by a horse rider carrying a lantern.  So the horse rider can simply shout a warning.

Comment: @Tim No, that was in The Netherlands.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [the Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code):

**[Rule 112](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/general-rules-techniques-and-advice-for-all-drivers-and-riders-103-to-158#rule112)**

**The horn.** Use only while your vehicle is moving and you need to warn other road users of your presence. Never sound your horn aggressively. You MUST NOT use your horn

- while stationary on the road
- when driving in a built-up area between the hours of 11.30 pm and 7.00 am

except when another road user poses a danger.

**Law [CUR reg 99](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1986/1078/regulation/99/made)**

**[Rule 195](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/using-the-road-159-to-203#rule195)**

**Zebra and parallel crossings.** As you approach a zebra crossing
...

- do not wave, flash your lights or use your horn to invite pedestrians across; this could be dangerous if another vehicle is approaching
- be patient, do not sound your horn or rev your engine as this can be intimidating
  ...

**[Rule 214](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/road-users-requiring-extra-care-204-to-225#rule214)**

**Animals.** When passing animals, drive slowly. Give them plenty of room and be ready to stop. Do not scare animals by sounding your horn ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137247/discussion-on-answer-by-lag-is-it-illegal-to-use-a-horn-in-circumstances-other-t).